# Your reply url contains prohibited words or prohibited domains: at the time configuration of android platform in Azure Microsoft platform

Tags: android, azure, kotlin, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am implementing login with Microsoft account in android application.

I have created Azure account and Set up a tenant in that I register one application with    Accounts in any organizational directory (Any Azure AD directory - Multitenant) and personal Microsoft accounts (e.g. Skype, Xbox) Account type

Now in this I am trying to configuring android application using Package name and SHA key at that time I am getting **Your reply url contains prohibited words or prohibited domains**

please help me to solve this issue thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show what the reply URL you are trying to add looks like? You can change actual package name and so on to fake values if you want.

Comment: @juunas for android platform reply url gets created automatically based on package name and signature hash

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me, and the only solution was to raise a support ticket with Microsoft. They confirmed that the domain I was using "is a sub match on another domain and currently forbidden", but added it to an "exemption list" and it began working. Took 13 calendar days to resolve.